# How to get only words instead of string from the input() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

```
from pygame import mixer
import pygame
while True:
    file = input('Drag music here : ')
    pygame.mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(file)
    mixer.music.play(0)
    while True:
        inp= input("Press enter to stop : \n")
        if inp == "":
            mixer.music.stop()
            break
```

save this code in a file and run with cmd and drag a music(mp3) file and press 'enter' to play it'll give an error i know why it happening but i can't solve it .

if i open this in cmd and drag a file in cmd then the directory comes with quotes and input() also takes argument as string so it gives me error.
Gimme a solution to take input as without quotes which will nor be string and become string after i drag the file.

Comment: Can you include the error as well as an image or a copy/paste of what you're saying happens after you drag a file into cmd? I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to describe

Comment: i have editted the whole code u can test it now , thanks :)    !

Comment: If CMD adds quotes around the value, `file.strip('"\'')`…!?

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked , God bless u   :)      .....